# How to authenticate Access Token in OAuth Resource Server

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, rest, oauth, oauth-2.0

I have 3 apps; OAuth 2.0 Authentication server that generate token, OAuth client who requests token, OAuth Resource server that provides Restful API. These are all MVC 3 web applications.
My question is how to validate Access Token that is arrived to OAuth resource server from the client?
For example, OAuth client received a response from the OAuth server with Access Token. And then client added this token into header before made a request to OAuth Resource Server to call one of API function.
Even though I can see the acces token in the headers[Authentication], I cannot find a way to validate this token.
Because I am using MVC3 to design Restful API via Area, I cannot use below function, which used with SOAP web service.

```
private static IPrincipal VerifyOAuth2(HttpRequestMessageProperty httpDetails, Uri requestUri, params string[] requiredScopes) {
        // for this sample where the auth server and resource server are the same site,
        // we use the same public/private key.
        using (var signing = PixidoRest.MvcApplication.CreateAuthorizationServerSigningServiceProvider())
        {
            using (var encrypting = PixidoRest.MvcApplication.CreateResourceServerEncryptionServiceProvider())
            {
                var resourceServer = new ResourceServer(new StandardAccessTokenAnalyzer(signing, encrypting));
                return resourceServer.GetPrincipal(httpDetails, requestUri, requiredScopes);
            }
        }
    }
```

Because I cannot path "HttpRequestMessageProperty", I am stuck there to validate AccesToken that I received from the client. How can I validate this on MVC 3 Restful API application as a Resource Server for OAuth Client?

Here are my other codes:

```
internal static RSACryptoServiceProvider CreateResourceServerEncryptionServiceProvider()
    {
        var resourceServerEncryptionServiceProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        resourceServerEncryptionServiceProvider.ImportParameters(ResourceServerEncryptionPrivateKey);
        return resourceServerEncryptionServiceProvider;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates the crypto service provider for the authorization server that contains the public key used to verify an access token signature.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>An RSA crypto service provider.</returns>
    internal static RSACryptoServiceProvider CreateAuthorizationServerSigningServiceProvider()
    {
        var authorizationServerSigningServiceProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        authorizationServerSigningServiceProvider.ImportParameters(AuthorizationServerSigningPublicKey);
        return authorizationServerSigningServiceProvider;
    }

public class RequireAuthorization : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public string Scope { get; set; }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext actionContext)
    {
        string[] scope = null;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Scope))
        {
            scope = Scope.Split(new[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        }

        var query = actionContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request;
        var req = actionContext.HttpContext;
        var authvalue = query.Headers["Authorization"];
        OAuthAuthorizationManager.VerifyOAuth2(query, query.Url.AbsoluteUri);
        //var response = new HttpResponseMessageProperty()
        //{
           //here is my question.
        //};


        base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);

        //redirect page to
        //if (CheckUrCondition)
        //{
        //actionContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new
        //{
        //    controller = "Home",
        //    action = "Index"
        //}));
        ////}
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you solve that? If so, please share!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and came up with the following custom Authorize attribute which works for me. Please note that my example relies on the ResourceServer property being injected with dependency injection. Of course, you could also have it point to a static instance as well.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

using DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging;
using DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2;

/// <summary>
/// Allows authorization to be applied to ASP.NET MVC methods where OAuth is used as the authorization mechanism.
/// </summary>
public class OAuthAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the resource server that will be used to process the access token
    /// that will be used to authorized.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The resource server.
    /// </value>
    /// <remarks>
    /// This property will most likely be set using dependency-injection.
    /// </remarks>
    public ResourceServer ResourceServer { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the scopes.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The required scopes.
    /// </value>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Multiple scopes can be used by separating them with spaces.
    /// </remarks>
    public string Scopes { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// When overridden, provides an entry point for custom authorization checks.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="httpContext">The HTTP context, which encapsulates all HTTP-specific information about an individual HTTP request.</param>
    /// <returns>
    /// true if the user is authorized; otherwise, false.
    /// </returns>
    /// <exception cref="System.InvalidOperationException">Thrown when the <see cref="ResourceServer"/> property is <c>null</c>.</exception>
    /// <exception cref="System.InvalidOperationException">Thrown when the <see cref="Scopes"/> property is <c>null</c>.</exception>
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        if (this.ResourceServer == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The ResourceServer property must not be null.");
        }

        try
        {
            this.StorePrincipalFromAccessToken(httpContext);

            return this.AccessTokenIsAuthorizedForRequestedScopes();
        }
        catch (ProtocolException)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Processes HTTP requests that fail authorization.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filterContext">Encapsulates the information for using <see cref="T:System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute" />. The <paramref name="filterContext" /> object contains the controller, HTTP context, request context, action result, and route data.</param>
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Stores the principal contained in the current access token.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="httpContext">The HTTP context.</param>
    protected virtual void StorePrincipalFromAccessToken(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        httpContext.User = this.ResourceServer.GetPrincipal();
        Thread.CurrentPrincipal = httpContext.User;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Check if the access token provided is authorized for the requested scopes.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected virtual bool AccessTokenIsAuthorizedForRequestedScopes()
    {
        return OAuthUtilities.SplitScopes(this.Scopes ?? string.Empty).IsSubsetOf(this.ResourceServer.GetAccessToken().Scope);
    }
}
```

You can now use this attribute as follows:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

public class DemoController : Controller
{
    [OAuthAuthorize(Scopes = "public")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return this.View();
    }
}
```